# Rails query records using full text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fuzzy-search

I'm wondering if it is possible to perform a Rails ActiveRecord query using a string that may or may not contain query-able text.

For example let's say I have a `Person` model with a `name` column, containing records with names of `Bob` and `Fred`. I'm wondering if there is some way for me to parse the following:

> I am having lunch with Bob and Martha today. Fred is busy.

With this the `Bob` and `Fred` records would be returned, and Martha would not because a record for that name does not exist. I imagine the query itself would look something like `Person.where('name IN (?)', ['Bob', 'Fred'])`?

In looking for the answer I've come across fuzzy searching, but it looks like it's more meant to find closest matches to specific queries (`catz` -> `cats`). Is this correct, or can I in fact use fuzzy searching for long string queries?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to go the other way and do Person.all than grep every person against your text.

Comment: @MikeK. No, that's wildly inefficient

Comment: Wouldn't pulling down every record each time slow everything down?

Comment: Yeah, that will be grossly inefficient.

Comment: Try looking into the Sunspot gem and running Apache Solr for full text searching.

Comment: @sjagr sure, but I mean the alternative of searching every word in a large corpus of text for an entry in the Person table would be wildly inefficient thats why things like Solr and ElasticSearch exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the problem, at a very high level is knowing which of the wording is a name and which is not.

For example... in:

```
I am having lunch with Bob and Martha today. Fred is busy.
```

There are 3 names. which we know, because we know `Fred`, `Bob` and `Martha` are names.

what about if someone's name is `Lunch`?

In this respect, I think splitting the sentence to an array of all the words, and doing a query where `name` is any of the words is a good bet.

So, in `I am having lunch with Bob and Martha today. Fred is busy`, you can get an array of the sentence as:

```
word_array = %w(I am having lunch with Bob and Martha today. Fred is busy)
```

and then perform a query to get records where name is any of the above:

```
Person.where('name IN (?)', word_array)
```

One more thing: you might want to [use gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) to first remove commas(,) and periods(.) before conversion into the array.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I think this could work. I don't expect, at least in my scenerio, to be searching amongst huge paragraphs -- just short little sentences like above. Thank you! I'll give it a whirl.